# Getting the values of a child in XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have the current XML file:

```
<test>
<class name="something" class="some"> 
<field> 
 <name>something</name> 
 <location>Something.class</location>
 <desc></desc> 
</field>
</class>
</test>
```

And to parse the XML file, I have the following piece of code:

```
    public static void parse(){
       try {
       File xml = new File("testfile.xml");
           DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
           Document document = db.parse(xml);

           NodeList node = document.getChildNodes();
           Element root = (Element) node.item(0);
           NodeList classes = root.getElementsByTagName("class");
           for(int i = 0; i < classes.getLength(); i++){
               Node nodes = classes.item(i);
               Element classElement = (Element) nodes;
               System.out.println("Class name: " + classElement.getAttribute("name"));
               System.out.println("Location: " + classElement.getAttribute("class"));
           }

       } catch (Exception ignored){

       }
}
```

But I have no idea to get the values of the field element it's children. I only got the element by using:

```
NodeList classes = root.getElementsByTagName("field");
```

My question is, how would I get those values in the element field?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.getChildNodes()` in the `field` node just as you did to the `root`:

```
Node field = root.getElementsByTagName("field").item(0);
NodeList fieldChildren = field.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < fieldChildren.getLength(); i++) {
    Node n = fieldChildren.item(i);
    System.out.println("Node Type: " + n.getNodeName());
    System.out.println("Node Value: \"" + n.getTextContent()+"\"");
}
```

Output (for your file):

```
Node Type: #text
Node Value: " 
 "
Node Type: name
Node Value: "something"
Node Type: #text
Node Value: " 
 "
Node Type: location
Node Value: "Something.class"
Node Type: #text
Node Value: "
 "
Node Type: desc
Node Value: ""
Node Type: #text
Node Value: " 
"
```

The `#text` nodes are the spaces in between `<name>`, `<location>` and `<desc>`.

#### Edit:

For multiple fields, consider the following XML:

```
<test>
    <class name="something" class="some">
        <field>
            <name>something</name>
            <location>Something.class</location>
            <desc/>
        </field>
    </class>
    <class name="something2" class="some2">
        <field>
            <name>something2</name>
            <location>Something.class2</location>
            <desc>2</desc>
        </field>
        <field>
            <name>something22</name>
            <location>Something.class22</location>
            <desc>22</desc>
        </field>
    </class>
</test>
```

Use the code:

```
NodeList fields = root.getElementsByTagName("field");
for (int fi = 0; fi < fields.getLength(); fi++) {
    Node field = fields.item(fi);
    NodeList fieldChildren = field.getChildNodes();
    System.out.println("Processing Field #"+fi+":");
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldChildren.getLength(); i++) {
        Node n = fieldChildren.item(i);
        System.out.println("\tNode Type: " + n.getNodeName());
        System.out.println("\tNode Value: \"" + n.getTextContent()+"\"");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Processing Field #0:
    Node Type: name
    Node Value: "something"
    Node Type: location
    Node Value: "Something.class"
    Node Type: desc
    Node Value: ""
Processing Field #1:
    Node Type: name
    Node Value: "something2"
    Node Type: location
    Node Value: "Something.class2"
    Node Type: desc
    Node Value: "2"
Processing Field #2:
    Node Type: name
    Node Value: "something22"
    Node Type: location
    Node Value: "Something.class22"
    Node Type: desc
    Node Value: "22"
```

Comment: You can use the [`Node.getNodeType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeType()) method to filter out the `#text` nodes by checking to see if `nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE`.

Comment: Thank you. What if I have more field entries? How would I do that? Your code worked fine, but not for more entries.

Comment: It's the `Node field = root.getElementsByTagName("field").item(0);` part. It just gets the first `field`. I'll edit it to make it clearer on how to get more.

Comment: @acdcjunior Unfortunately I am getting a different output:

Processing Field #0:
Processing Field #1:
Processing Field #2:

Until my last entry (160).